# Cocoa WebView reloads on first click

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

I have an OS X application with a WebView that reloads the WebView on the first click if the click is not on a link within the view.

Any suggestions of how to hunt this down? I assumed it would have to do with focus, but I thought maybe someone had encountered something like this before.

Thanks, Charlie

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your code somewhere you are loading it manually something like this:-

```
[[webView mainFrame]loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
```